# Double click on selected ListBox item

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have listbox with items from observablecollection.

```
 <ListBox Name="listBoxData"
          DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource MainWindowViewModelDataSource}}" 
          ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource BookTemplate}"                                 
          ItemsSource="{Binding Books, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedBook, Mode=TwoWay}">
```

Question is how to wire double click action on selected item?

I do not avoid code behind approach (which is currently empty, all my logic is inside mvvm).

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2547442/wpf-listboxitem-double-click

Answer (score 0):

Your final line is a little confusing... to me, it says 'a code behind solution is ok', but then you mention MVVM, so I'm not sure. Either way, here is a simple answer for you. Declare the `ListBox`:

```
<ListBox SelectionChanged="ListBox_SelectionChanged" />
```

And then in the code behind, assuming single selection mode:

```
private void ListBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    ListBoxItem listBoxItem = (ListBoxItem)e.AddedItems[0];
    listBoxItem.PreviewMouseDoubleClick += ListBoxItem_PreviewMouseDoubleClick;
    listBoxItem = (ListBoxItem)e.RemovedItems[0];
    listBoxItem.PreviewMouseDoubleClick -= ListBoxItem_PreviewMouseDoubleClick;
}

private void ListBoxItem_PreviewMouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    // Selected item was double clicked
}
```

If you want the MVVM way, then you can just move the code from the `ListBox_SelectionChanged` handler to the `SelectedBook` setter and the `ListBoxItem_PreviewMouseDoubleClick` handler to the view model. However, it's not such a good idea handling UI events in the view model. It's better to use Attached Properties to handle them for you, but that's another story.