# WPF: how do i handle a click on a ListBox item?

Tags: c#, wpf, listboxitem

In my WPF app I'm handling a ListBox SelectionChanged event and it runs fine.

Now I need to handle a click event (even for the already selected item); I've tried MouseDown but it does not work. How can I handle a ListBox click on an item?

Comment: This is answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/821609/58768

Comment: @modosansreves that question asks about Click. Click is special. Apparently hijacked and turned into SelectionChanged. DoubleClick is not...

Comment: Here is a similar question; whose answer is a nice summary of all approaches. http://stackoverflow.com/q/1271375/1175496

Answer (score 37):

Just handle PreviewMouseDown event:

```
private void listBox_PreviewMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    var item = ItemsControl.ContainerFromElement(listBox, e.OriginalSource as DependencyObject) as ListBoxItem;
    if (item != null)
    {
        // ListBox item clicked - do some cool things here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Perhaps try the [`PreviewMouseDown`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.previewmousedown.aspx) event. The `MouseDown` event gets swallowed and converted to the `SelectionChanged` event.

Only downside is that the `PreviewMouseDown` will occur before the `SelectionChanged`.

Answer (score 4):

Listbox internally uses the mouse down to perform selection changed. So you can use preview mouse down event.

Apart from preview mouse down, you can use EventManager.RegisterClassHandler...

```
     EventManager.RegisterClassHandler(typeof(ListBoxItem), ListBoxItem.MouseLeftButtonDownEvent, new RoutedEventHandler(EventBasedMouseLeftButtonHandler));

     private static void EventBasedMouseLeftButtonHandler(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
     {
     }
```

Let me know if this helps...