# DoubleClick on my ListBox item is not being fired

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I am implementing a listbox using MVVM approach and I'm having an issue where my double click command is not being triggered. When I launch my application I see my ListBox populated via binding just fine. But when I double click on an item nothing happens. Is there something I'm missing? Many thanks in advance.

Here is how I have my **UserControl (xaml)** set up

```
    <ListBox 
        x:Name="Files" 
        ItemsSource="{Binding FileCollection, Mode=TwoWay}"
        SelectedItem="{Binding Filename, Mode=TwoWay}">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding}">                                    
                    <TextBlock.InputBindings>
                        <MouseBinding  
                         Gesture="LeftDoubleClick" 
                         Command="{Binding EditFileCommand}"/>
                    </TextBlock.InputBindings>
               </TextBlock>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

This is how I am setting up my command object in my **View Model**:

```
        //..using system.windows.input for ICommand
        private ICommand editFileCommand = null;
        public ICommand EditFileCommand
        {
            get
            {
                //RelayCommand comes from GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Command
                return editFileCommand ?? new RelayCommand(EditFile); 
            }
        }

        private void EditFile()
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Double Click!");
        }
```

Comment: Did you already check out [those](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6938752/wpf-how-do-i-handle-a-click-on-a-listbox-item) SO [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10207888/wpf-listview-detect-when-selected-item-is-clicked)?

Comment: @dymanoid Thank you for the prompt reply. I checked them out but they don't seem to be using MVVM.

Comment: @user2529011: Where is the command defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is almost similar to `RelayCommand`, you can use it like this:

Declare in your ViewModel:

```
public RelayCommand EditFileCommand { get; set; }
```

Then, you need to initialize it:

```
EditFileCommand = new RelayCommand(EditFile);
```

The XAML remains equal:

```
<ListBox 
        x:Name="Files" 
        ItemsSource="{Binding FileCollection, Mode=TwoWay}"
        SelectedItem="{Binding Filename, Mode=TwoWay}">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding}">                                    
                    <TextBlock.InputBindings>
                        <MouseBinding  
                         Gesture="LeftDoubleClick" 
                         Command="{Binding EditFileCommand}"/>
                    </TextBlock.InputBindings>
               </TextBlock>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

Comment: thaaaaaaaaank youuuuuu! I did some more digging on RelayCommand and not only does it inherit from ICommand but just making my object RelayCommand I didnt have to do all that extra stuff to my EditFileCommand. Just one line to initialize and done. Thank you again. Rock on!

Answer (score 1):

If the command property is defined in the `File` class, it should work provided that you actually click on the `TextBlock`. You could make the `TextBlock` stretch across the `ListBoxItem` container by using an `ItemContainerStyle`:

```
<ListBox x:Name="Files" ...>
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
            <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            ...
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

If the command is defined in the view model where the `FileCollection` property is defined, you should use a `RelativeSource`:

```
<TextBlock.InputBindings>
    <MouseBinding  Gesture="LeftDoubleClick" 
                   Command="{Binding DataContext.EditFileCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListBox}}"/>
</TextBlock.InputBindings>
```